# CSS Font Styles - Rubber Stamp effect

Tags: css

I am looking for a CSS font that would be as close as possible to what a rubber stamp would do.

For example something close to this:

[image]

I prefer not to use an image because the text is dynamic.

I anyone can offer some advise on how to do this, I would appreciate it.

**UPDATE**

This question appears to be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37504626/css-effect-to-render-a-font-with-rubber-stamp-effect)

Comment: Not exactly the same but kinda similar : http://www.1001fonts.com/top-secret-font.html

Comment: Closest one I can find is a premium font from fonts.com: https://www.fonts.com/font/itc/rubber-stamp

Comment: be careful not to share commercial images on QA sites. Instead provide a link

Answer (score 3):

Not really a font but it will just load a small image *once* which can be used any number of times you want to generate a similar text.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  color: red;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 10px red;
}

h1:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/5O74VI6.jpg");
  mix-blend-mode: lighten;
}
```

```html
<h1>
CANCELLED
</h1>
```